# Android: Performance drops in project after migrating to androidx and swiping in ListView

Tags: java, android, performance, gpu, androidx

I recently migrated an old Android project to AndroidX, and after the migration, I've been experiencing significant drops in performance when swiping inside a ListView.
I have captured GPU rendering speed, which clearly show the long processing.

Screenshots:
Before androidx
[image: Before androidx]

After androidx
[image: After androidx]

Libraries in Use that may cause the issue:

1. https://github.com/alexandrius/accordion-swipe-layout
2. https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel
3. https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Other libraries that were migrated to androidX

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile('com.android.support:design:26.1.0') {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
```

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this performance issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!